# Unable to map the error getting from the application deployed using lambda function

Tags: spring-boot, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am having springboot application deployed using a lambda function. Please find the below sample.

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/bugnlow/findByRegionId/{regionId}", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<List<Bunglow>> findAllBunglowsByRegionId(@PathVariable int regionId, @RequestParam int page, @RequestParam int size) {
Page<Bunglow> bunglows = bunglowsService.findAllBunglowsByRegionId(regionId, page, size);
if (bunglows.getContent().size() == 0){
    return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
}
return ResponseEntity.ok(bunglows.getContent());
}
```

Service

```
if the "regionid" is invalid, I am throwing a runtime exception that contains message "region id is invalid".
throw new RuntimeException(Constant.INVALID_REGION_ID);
```

I am getting the below response when testing it locally by sending the invalid region id.

```
[1]{
  "timestamp": 1519577956092,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "java.lang.RuntimeException",
  "message": "Region Id is invalid",
  "path": "/***/bugnlow/findByRegionId/343333"
}
```

I deployed above application AWS using lambda function. When I send the request from the AWS API gateway to the deployed application I am getting the below error with Amazon response headers.

```
[2] Request: /bugnlow/findByRegionId/342324?page=0&size=5 Status: 500 Latency: 166 ms Response Body
{  "message": "Internal server error" }
```

In the particular endpoint, integration responses have already configured for Error 500. But didn't use a template configuring the content-type as application/json.

I able to get the localized error by setting it in the controller class with

```
ResponseEntity<?>
```

But then the List Bunglow not display as the example response value in Swagger UI.

1. I need to get exact response[1] from the AWS console. How to do it.
2. Instead of error 500, how can I send the "Region id is invalid" with the Http status 400 (bad request).

It's a great help, if someone can help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I able to resolve my problem by creating a class with

```
@ControllerAdvice
```

and handle the Exception using

```
@ExceptionHandler
```

Each point I need to validate and respond the error, I created an custom Exception "BunglowCustomExceptionResponse" and catch the exception in the Advice class "BunglowControllerAdvice". Then send the response with the exception message with bad request response as below.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class BunglowControllerAdvice {
    @ExceptionHandler
    public ResponseEntity handleCustomBunglowException(Exception e){
        logger.info("***Exception occurred  :" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<BunglowCustomExceptionResponse>(new 
BunglowCustomExceptionResponse(e.getLocalizedMessage()), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Then, I able to get the expected response similar to below with bad request status code 400.

```
{"responseMessage": "error message"}
```

I don't know this is the best way but able to resolve my problem. Anyway, thanks a lot for your time who viewed this and tried to help me.